# How to determine if a non-empty string exists in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword-argument

I often find myself checking dictionaries in python to see if a key is in the dictionary and if the key has useful information (in my case, a nonzero-length string). For instance, I seem to often need to check kwargs for data like this:

```
if ('partition' not in kwargs or kwargs['partition'] is None
    or kwargs['partition'] == ""):
    raise Exception("Need 'partition' for this method")
```

Is there a simpler, straightforward way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: `if not kwargs.get('partition'):`

Comment: Does that still work if the key is not in the kwargs dictionary?

Comment: So you want to make sure that even if the 'partition' key exists it has to have something?

Comment: `kwargs.get("partition", "") is ""` Feel like there should be a neater way then this, though

Comment: Yes, I want the key to exist and have a nonzero length string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dictionary object's `get()` method and let Python determine its [truthiness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truthiness) automatically:

```
if not d.get('partition'):
    raise Exception("Need 'partition' for this method")
```

Comment: Based on the extra question in the comments, I believe they also want to check that the value for the key is not empty as well. So even if the key exists, it has to have something. Waiting for OP to confirm that in the comments. Keep an eye out for that.

Comment: This would not raise if the value was an empty string. `kwargs.get("partition", "") is ""` would.

Comment: I don't think the explicit cast is necessary. Python already does an implicit coercion

Answer (score 1):

Which approach is Pythonic might depend on whether the dictionary contents are an internal or external interface.

If you're writing a library, working with dictionary contents read from the command line or files, or something similar where you the programmer are not in charge of the contents, you'd want to do something like what you've written in the OP as good defensive programming practice.  If this is a common enough idiom in your code, you may want to write a function that provides similar handling while generalizing over the specific key that you're looking for, such as:

```
def key_contains_contents(user_dict, key):
    return (key in user_dict) and user_dict[key] and len(user_dict[key]) > 0
```

Add additional clauses as necessary.

If the contents of the dict are created by your program itself, you might as well come up with a standard way to express whether a key contains meaningful data and stick to that.  The specific problem you're solving may suggest one way or another that makes the code creating the dict simpler.  Absent any other constraints though, just not having the key set in the first place seems the simplest.